# Haskell Container class

Tags: haskell

Is there a good standard (or just stable) implementation of (ordered) Container class?

Container class should provide basic manipulation operations with it's `instance`s. Typical instances should be: Array, List, e.t.c.

Operations are:

- take `n`'th  element from container;
- take `n` first element's of container;
- and so on.

Why do I need this? With the help of this class I can, for example, define some function for processing something in container, and use it with any container that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may find [ListLike](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike) interesting. `index` and `take`, respectively, cover the two operations you mentioned and it includes some 'typical instances'.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of. This isn't Java so typeclass hierarchies are pretty rare. However, I think foldable is what you want

```
fold :: Monoid m => t m -> m
foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

An example index function,

```
index i = snd . foldl' choose (0, Nothing)
  where choose (j, Just x) _  = (j, Just x)
        choose (j, Nothing) x | i == j    = (i, Just x)
                              | otherwise = (j + 1, Nothing)
```

Now using this you can trivially flatten any collection to a list and treat it as such, and there are more intelligent ways to fold over a collection and keep the ith entry.

To modify it, you could use traversable. It's another class with a few functions based around

```
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t a)
```

Comment: No, exactly I want operations of returning by index (or range of indices). I don't need folds.

Comment: @AnonImous Then you are out of luck. There's the somewhat unknown `Keyed` interface, but this isn't really what you want. However, why not just create the index function with a fold, it's not that hard.

Comment: @AnonImous I added an example

Comment: @jozefgI I think your example will work ineffective on arrays. Sure, I can make it myself, but I don't want to reinvent bicycles.

Comment: @AnonImous Then create a new `Indexed` class and add that as a default implementation and add a more efficient interface for an `Array`.

Comment: @jozefgI Yes, I can do this, but using of some ready solution is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Data.Key.Indexed
has several instances, including List, IntMap, and more

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys-0.2.2/docs/Data-Key.html#g:5